# First and last bars in bar graph off the graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to put 5 bars on a bar graph with symbolic labels on the x-axis. The following code nearly works but the first and last bars are partially off the graph area. I've looked a dozen+ examples of similar questions but I can't seem to find one that matches my problem (that I want all the bars in the graph area. My WME ( believe it's called) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
                        bar width=40pt,
                        xlabel={Classes},
                        ylabel={Class Count},   
                        ymin=0,
                        ymax=60,
                        ytick ={0,10,20,30,40,50,60},
                        xtick =data,
                        axis x line=bottom,
                        axis y line=left,
                        symbolic x coords={0-10,11-20,21-30,31-40,41-50}
]
            \addplot plot[draw=black, fill=gray] coordinates {
                        (0-10, 5)
                        (11-20,30)
                        (21-30,50)
                        (31-40,20)
                        (41-50,15)
                        };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I couln''t figure out how to add an image of the output. I'm still learning this interface.

Comment: Unrelated: You should always set compat level for PGFPlots - `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `enlarge x limits`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
bar width=30pt,
xlabel={Classes},
ylabel={Class Count},   
ymin=0, ymax=60,
ytick ={0,10,20,30,40,50,60},
xtick =data,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
symbolic x coords={0-10,11-20,21-30,31-40,41-50},
enlarge x limits=0.2,
]
\addplot plot[black, fill=gray] coordinates {
(0-10, 5)
(11-20,30)
(21-30,50)
(31-40,20)
(41-50,15)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bargraph]

Here are the same graph with `enlarge x limits=0.5` and `bar width=20pt`:

[image: Bargraph with more space]

When using PGFPlots you should always use `\pgfplotsset{compat=...}`. This sets the version of PGFPlots used. PGFPlots evolve and new versions will behave different from old versions. The above code does not compile differently with different `compat` levels. -but that does not guarantee that the output does not change or break in future versions. That is why it is important to hardcode the `compat` level.

Comment: Thanks. I tried enlarge but it didn't work for me. I guess it needed the compat=1.18 as well -- I've no idea what it means.

Comment: I'm confused. I tried incrementing the counter and it just toggles between 0 an 1. How come I see higher scores next to other answer!?

Comment: I do not fully understand. `compat=1.18` is not needed for it to work. If your LaTeX installation is not updated, you will not have version 1.18 and you can with no problem use e.g. `1.16` - or maybe it is time to update your packages.

Comment: What counter -the upvote? You can only upvote once for each question/answer.

Comment: My version of LateX is 20.2 - just installed. I'm guessing from your comment that compat=1.18 is a compatibility key. I tried using enlarge x limits =0.5 (lifted from some answers I saw - looked promising - but it did nothing. But the above code works fine. I am a little bewildered, but that's okay - seems to be my natural state.

Comment: Yes, the upvote. So, how come I see large numbers beside answered question?

Comment: @TonyK: See edit. When multiple people upvote, the number gets higher.